# NameError: name 'FSMContext' is not defined

Tags: python, aiogram

Работаю с "Машиной" в aiogram. Выдает ошибку:

```
@dp.message_handler(state=change.text_key)
async def check_text_key(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
```

Ошибка: NameError: name 'FSMContext' is not defined. В чем проблема?

Comment: А импорт сделан: `from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext`?

Comment: xD, не было...))

Comment: Чудес не бывает. Если программа что-то не видит, то это либо не импортировано, либо не определено, либо не присвоено... )